# Computationally Inexpensive Image Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I am new in machine learning domain. We have some videos of the cattle farm. All cattle are being detected by the YoloV2.

In one frame/min, we have to feed all cattle's image to a model and determine where each one of them is laying or standing. The problem is more like - cat vs dog (laying vs standing).

Can someone please suggest any computationally inexpensive image classifier to accomplish the objective?

I am planning to train the model with 200 images/class and 70-80 % accuracy is good enough at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at classifiers for mobile phones. They are usually quite performant and still decently accurate. The most common one is MobileNet, but there are newer variants nowadays. You do need to finetune the classifier though. An example on how to do this with keras can be found here: https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-mobilenet-and-keras-c75daf7ff299 .

Answer (score 1):

If you want computationally inexpensive image classifier, you have to re-train object detection model.

1. train new model that is suitable for only cattle prediction.

It means you need to prepare two class of images(laying cattles and standing cattles)

After preparing images, build new model that consists of 2 class classifier, not 80 class or 20 class classifier (usually in YOLOv2).

Because you want computationally inexpensive model. and you don't need other classes in your classifier.